# Create records with associated tables in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

I am new to ruby on rails and don't understand how to create and save records using associated tables. I want the controller to take the data create a product record and then create as many property and product properties associated with that product.  The property and product property have a one to one relationship.  The product can have many properties and product properties.

Properties and product properties are coming in like this:

```
{"name"=>"color", "value"=>"red"}
{"name"=>"material", "value"=>"cotton"}
```

My controller works for the creation of the product but I am unsure how to create a loop that will build as may associated product and product properties that come in the array sent from the client.

My controller now:

```
class SendDataController < ApplicationController
    protect_from_forgery with: :null_session

    def hi
        product = Product.new
        product.name = params[:name]
        product.upc = params[:upc].to_i
        product.available_on = params[:availableon]
        product.save
    end    
end
```

Below are my models:

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :propertys, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :product_propertys, dependent: :destroy
end

class Property < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :product
    has_one :product_property, dependent: :destroy
end

class ProductProperty < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :property
    belongs_to :product
end
```

Migration:

```
class CreateProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :products do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :upc
      t.datetime :available_on

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateProductProperties < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :product_properties do |t|
      t.string :value
      t.belongs_to :property
      t.belongs_to :product

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateProperties < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :properties do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.belongs_to :product

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

schema:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2018_09_22_140824) do

  create_table "product_properties", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "value"
    t.integer "property_id"
    t.integer "product_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["product_id"], name: "index_product_properties_on_product_id"
    t.index ["property_id"], name: "index_product_properties_on_property_id"
  end

  create_table "products", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "upc"
    t.datetime "available_on"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "properties", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.integer "product_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["product_id"], name: "index_properties_on_product_id"
  end

end
```

Thanks for any help you can give a new guy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **Product Model** plurality required, *has_many* properties & equally has_many product_properties.

Your **Property** schema will need product_id as an integer. i would avoid using *has_one* it can get messy, just use has_many or you may require a *has_many* *through*

Your **ProductProperty Model** You'll also need product_id integer & property_id integer adding them as separate migration.

*rails db:create add_product_id_to product_properties, product_id:integer*
check the migration file *product_id* that the attribute is in the file
*rails db:migrate*
Restart server & test in the console.

Once the Models speak, instantiate a Product object, bring it across into Properties & ProductProperties through the respective controllers by setting & in turn making the   **SendDataController** obsolete unless your logic requires this.

Comment: Add schema to bottom of my question.

Comment: In rails console instantiate a  product  p = Product.create( add attributes as a hash here)  to check product associates with associations work calling by p.properties.all